# Free advanced dropdown list control (Windows Forms .Net)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, combobox

I'm looking for a free advanced dropdown list control. Basically something that provides a dropdown list which can have icons, and multiple bits of text per entry (preferably one large bit of text and then a smaller bit of text underneath).

Anyone know of such a control? I've had a look but can't seem to find one.

If I can't find it I spose I'll have to create it myself. I've done a bit with custom controls but I'm not really sure how I'd go about this...how would one take a ComboBox or something but make each entry completely graphically customisable?

Any links to controls, or hints on how to create one would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a drop down list, but I think you can use the knowledge [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/OAKListView.aspx) to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything on the free side of WinForms that lets you do this.  If you have green fields, however, WPF gives you what you're looking for out of the box.

Comment: That might be a possibility. I have no experience with WPF - what control in WPF does this automatically?

Comment: All list controls allow you to composite items, so you could take an object bound to a combo box and display it any way you want.  See http://tinyurl.com/af6w7u for a good read on this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com) which is free.